# Inject custom type conversion to .NET library classes

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I would like to implement conversion between two library classes by Convert.ChangeType in C#. I can change neither of the two types. For example converting between Guid and byte[].

```
Guid g = new Guid();
object o1 = g;
byte[] b = (byte[]) Convert.ChangeType(o1, typeof(byte[])); // throws exception
```

I am aware that Guid provides a ToByteArray() method, but I would like to have that called when Guid is converted to byte[]. The reason behind this is that the conversion also takes place in library code (AseDataAdapter) which I can not modify. So is it possible to define a conversion rule between two types without modifying the sourcecode of either of the two classes?

I was experimenting with TypeConverter, but doesn't seem to work either:

```
Guid g = new Guid();
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Guid));
byte[] b2 = (byte[])tc.ConvertTo(g, typeof(byte[])); // throws exception
```

The variable tc gets set to System.ComponentModel.GuidConverter which doesn't support conversions to byte[]. Can I have two TypeConverters for the same class? Even if I could, wouldn't I need to prepend an attribute to the source code of the class to assign a TypeConverter?

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can change the registered `TypeConverter` for something using `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes`; this isn't quite the same as `Convert.ChangeType`, but it may suffice:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Guid), new TypeConverterAttribute(
            typeof(MyGuidConverter)));

        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(guid);
        byte[] data = (byte[])conv.ConvertTo(guid, typeof(byte[]));
        Guid newGuid = (Guid)conv.ConvertFrom(data);
    }
}

class MyGuidConverter : GuidConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(byte[]) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(byte[]) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            return new Guid((byte[])value);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            return ((Guid)value).ToByteArray();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Didn't even realise you could add attributes via TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes - that could be extremely useful.

Comment: Note that they aren't *real* attributes - reflection won't see them; only System.ComponentModel

Comment: Marc, could you elaborate on using a custom `TypeDescriptorProvider` and overloading the `GetTypeDescriptor`->`GetConverter` chain? It seems to produce the same results and is slightly cleaner to actually register using `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider`, although it is quite a bit more verbose of course as you need to create both a `TypeDescriptorProvider` and a `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. Does registering it that way completely overwrites the standard `TypeDescriptor` for that object, or does it composse with the existing registrations?

Answer (score 0):

If the code that is performing the conversion supports `TypeConverter`s you can use `TypeConverterAttribute` at an assembly level.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no assembly-level usage of TypeConverterAttribute; you can do per-type and per-property, and override either via TypeDescriptor - but no assembly level? Have I missed something?

Comment: TypeConverterAttribute is declared AttributeTargets.All... and ISTR seeing this used in WF.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor
```

Yes, it is possible. Read the documentation on MSDN for related information to 'inject' that into the running program.  (TypeDescriptor provides the method IIRC).

Comment: That is massively overkill... either use [TypeConverter] on an individual property (respected by PropertyDescriptor), or use the global approach shown in my post.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately no you cannot - you could write an extension method that would *appear* to be a conversion between two types as part of the framework.