# A Custom type converter while parsing IConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) it is possible to parse `IConfiguraton` and cast it into an object of type of the desired class by using `config.Get<MyConfigClass>()`.

Example:

```cs
public class MyConfigClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class StartUp
{
    public MyConfigClass MyConfig { get; }
    public StartUp(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.MyConfigClass = config.Get<MyConfigClass>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

This works fine. However, I'm wonderng if it is possible to use a custom type insinde `MyConfigClass`?

Example:

Could the `Location` field use its corresponding type `Loc` that provides a `Parse` method?
I tried naively changing the `MyConfigClass` to this:

```cs
public class MyConfigClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Loc Location { get; set; }
}
```

But then the field `Location` contained the value `null`.
Is it possible to provide the `Get<'T>` method with a set of custom converters to use?

Comment: How would the framework know how to convert a string into a `Loc`? Does it have an explicit/implicit operator? If it just has sub-properties, then make those properties nested in your json file too.

Comment: `How would the framework know how to convert a string into a Loc? ` - That's exactly what I'm asking. Some libraries (e.g. `CommandLineParser` for cmd args) allow to specify a custom string-to-type converter.

Comment: Normally, the config will read the json file inside the asp.net core, its json format. I also confused about why you are not use the right json format to get the value.

Comment: ```I also confused about why you are not use the right json format to get the value``` that's not true and I haven't said that. I'm asking if I can provide a custom converter between string and my type.

Comment: E.g. [this library](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) for parsing command line parameters allows users to provide a ```string -> 'T``` constructor and uses it automatically, making to configuration object well-typed.

Answer (score 0):

IConfiguration seems to respect existing type converters, so registering a TypeConverter that will convert from String to Loc should do the trick.

Further information on how to do this can be found at [Inject custom type conversion to .NET library classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606854/inject-custom-type-conversion-to-net-library-classes)

Note, I haven't tried this with Get, but it does work with Bind which seems to go through the same path to retreive values.